# Duplicate and group rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was hoping it wouldn't be too difficult to duplicate and group rows in Google sheets, but I've reached my wits end. I've attached a couple photos of how I would like the function to work. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Before running the duplicate and group functions(notice, oranges are already grouped):
[image: Start of function]

What I would like (items are grouped)
[image: End of function]

If it's easier, this could be an alternative acceptable solution
[image: Alt End of function]

```
function autoDup() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for(var n in data){
    newData.push(data[n]);
    if(!Number(data[n][3])){continue};// if column 3 is not a number then do nothing
    for(var c=0 ; c < Number(data[n][3]) ; c++){
      newData.push(data[n]);//store values
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);// write new data to sheet, overwriting old data
}

function autoGroup() {
}
```

**Update**

I was able to get the "alternative acceptable solution" working thanks to @tedinoz! The code is split into two functions for now, autoDup and autoGroup.

Here is the code:

```
function autoDup(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rowLen = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,rowLen,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues().sort();

  dataRange.expandGroups().shiftRowGroupDepth(-1);

  var newData = [];

  data = removeDups(data, rowLen);

  for(var n in data){
    
    newData.push(data[n]);
    var qty = data[n][2];

    if(!Number(qty)){continue};
    if(qty !== 1){
      for(var c=0 ; c < qty ; c++){
        newData.push([data[n][0],data[n][1],1]);//store values
      }
    }
  }
  // write new data to sheet, overwriting old data
  sheet.getRange(2,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).clearContent().setValues(newData);

}

function removeDups(data, dataLen){

  var newData = []

  for(var i=0; i<dataLen; i++){

    var valLast = data[i-1];
    var valCurrent = data[i];
    var valNext = data[i+1];

    if(valCheck(valCurrent, valNext)){
      continue;
    }else if(valCheck(valCurrent, valLast)){
      continue;
    }else {
      newData.push(valCurrent)
    }
  }
  
  return newData;
}

function autoGroup(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rowLen = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,rowLen,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for(var i=0, j=0, r=0; i<rowLen; i++){
    
    var valCurrent = data[i];
    var valNext = data[i+1];

    if(valCheck(valCurrent, valNext)){
      if(j === 0){
       j++;
       r = i + 2;
      }else j++;
    }else {
      if(j !== 0){
        sheet.getRange(r,1,j+1).activate().shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
        j=0;
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.collapseAllRowGroups();

}

function valCheck(value1,value2){
  if(value1 != null && value2 != null){
    if(value1.join() === value2.join()){
      return true;
    }else return false;
  }else return false;
}
```

Comment: The order given does not make any sense.  What is your ordering algorithm?

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: What's `autoDup()` supposed to do?

Comment: @Cooper the order isn't a concern of mine, just grouping the similar items.

Comment: @Tedinoz autoDup() is supposed to duplicate the rows for the quantity of items. Then i figured, i would have another function group everything nicely but I have no idea where to begin there.

Comment: `notice, oranges are already grouped` Is it possible that a new value will be added for Oranges and so the entire data set for Oranges will need to be reset. On a tangent, there appears to be some inconsistency with the data for "Banana" (Row#7) - in the first (raw data) image it is not grouped AND it doesn't have a Type BUT it has a Quantity. However in the two lower images, "Banana" is grouped and the number of grouped rows is consistent with the quantity. Please ensure that your raw data is consistent with the expected outcome.

Comment: @Tedinoz The data is consistent with how I would like the functions to operate. If there are no more oranges to duplicate/group AND oranges are already duplicated/grouped -> continue to Bananas. So, I think autoDup() would have to skip grouped items.

Comment: `I think autoDup() would have to skip grouped items`. I think it would be more work to have it skip grouped items than not.

Comment: @Tedinoz I think a simple (If 'parent row' then continue to next 'parent row') would suffice at the beginning of autoDup(). I'm just not sure how to check that in google sheets api

Comment: Your question is complex and multi-faceted (and arguably off-topic). My guidance suggestion is process data as follows: **#1**: duplicate sheet, work on copy **#2**: degroup Col A. **#3**: delete rows where Type is blank. **#4**: for rows where qty is >1, create multiple new rows where qty value=1. **#5**: delete rows where qty>1. **#6**: sort range by Item by Type. **#7**: add "group headers". **#8**: group Col A by Item. **#9**: delete original sheet, rename "dup" sheet. Some may somewhat easier said than done, but I think it is a logical sequence that will result in your expected outcome.